# Play Youtube videos with Custome UI

Tags: android, youtube

I want to achieve this UI

[image: youtube]

I have tried this  [lib](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player)
and reach to this

[image]

i have these issues

- want to remove all native controllers like

  - video title
  - menu in top right
  - youtube button

I have tried WebUI but UI is mix from my custome and WebUI and i can not hide web UI controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **exoplayer** from **google** then override its *Video player UI* with your **new custom UI**
then use **YoutubeExtractor** to get **URL** from *Youtube public URL* and pass this URL to exo-player.